# How to configure Xfce not to differenciate between L/R Super keys?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I have been configuring Xfce hot keys and application shortcuts in Xfce 4.12 in Debian 9.
I configured the **Super L** key to activate the Whisker menu(xfce4-popup-whiskermenu), but it only works with the **Super L** key, I expect it to work with either of them.
Now, I added another entry in the Application shortcuts to the same command(xfce4-popup-whiskermenu) and added **Super R** key to it and it works, I can use either of the Super keys to activate the Whisker menu.
But there's a problem: *Some other* shortcuts involving **Super** keys does not work, for example, I have **Super+D** assigned to *show desktop* and **Super+Tab** for 'switch window for same application', neither of them work(there's other shortcuts too that doesn't work because of this).
Strangely though, some involving the **Super** key does continue to work, for example, **Super+E** to open Thunar does work.
One thing I  observed with shortcuts that do work is that they do not specify which **Super** key is added to them, but that too has exceptions(**Super+D**).

What is going on? How can I get Xfce not to distinguish between my L/R Super keys?